# The use of the humble infix 사옵 and 옵

Tags: speech-levels, polite-speech

Can someone please let me know phrases and instance where the humble suffix is used with Hasipsio-che ?

As in the common phrase:

> 그간 무고하셨사옵니까?
>
> Meanwhile have you been okay ?

Comment: That’s one of the unique infixes of the 하소서 register (_Hasoseo-che_), which is dated and included in the 하십시오 register (_Hasipsio-che_) by the modern taxonomy. That’s just the way you talk in the speech level. Are you asking the usage of the 하소서 register (_Hasoseo-che_)?

Comment: As Константин Ван mentioned, this sentence is written in 하소서체 which is the most humble honorific in Korean language and not used often in modern Korean. Nowadays, 하소서체 is mostly used in historical dramas or in prayers. For example, "주님, 자비를 베푸소서." is  the translation of "Lord, have mercy."
Anyway, if you want to change the sentence "그간 무고하셨사옵니까?" into 하십시오체, you can say "그간 무고하셨습니까?"

Answer (score 1):

The example sentence that you wrote

> "그간 무고하셨사옵니까?"

is the humble suffix that is used long time ago and is not used quite often during these days. You might be able to see those humble suffix in Korean history series. That humble suffix is pretty much as humble as Hasipsio-che.

Hasipsio-che could be normally used whenever you need to deliver message very politely to other people. The best example could be when you are to publicy announce something important to the multiple audience. For instance,

> 현재 이 도로는 공사 중이니 우회하여 돌아가주십시오
> (As the road is under construction, please de tour to other routes.)

or

> 이곳은 관계자 외 출입이 제한되오니 용무가 있으신 분께서는 안내소로 먼저 와 주십시오.
> (Only authorized personnel can enter this place. For any help, please visit to the information desk first.)

Hasipsio-che could be sometimes used in particular circumstances where people should be polite. The best example is in army where lower-class soldier should always use Hasipsio-che when they talk to upper-class soldier.